# How to use nonstandard audio sample rate data with audio DAC?

Tags: audio, dac

In Table 1 the [CS4334 data sheet](https://www.cirrus.com/en/pubs/proDatasheet/CS4334-5-8-9_F6.pdf) states that it accepts standard audio sample rates in kHz of 32, 44.1, 48, 64, 88.2 & 96.

[image: Table 1]

What does one do to get correct output if the audio data sample rate is not one of these number or is less than 32kHz?

Comment: Define "correct output". The datasheet states: *"This architecture allows for infinite adjustment of sample rate between 2kHz and 100kHz simply by changing the master clock frequency."* Does this not meet your need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't my area of expertise, but from reading the datasheet I've gotten the following:

*"This architecture allows for infinite adjustment of sample rate between 2 kHz and 100 kHz simply by changing the master clock frequency"*

*"MCLK must be either 256x, 384x or 512x the desired input sample rate in BRM and either 128x or 192x the desired input sample rate in HRM".*

What I gather from that is that as long as you match your master clock to your input frequency the chip sets the internal dividers itself.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to confirm that.

Answer (score 3):

I only briefly looked at the datasheet.  This chip has a clock input called MCLK.  Again, I didn't read the details, but it certainly appears to be synchronous to that clock.  You should be able to get the chip to work over a wide range of sample rates by varying the clock.  There also appears to be some choice of scaling internal to the chip for a given clock.

Surely the details of that are to be found in the datasheet if you read it carefully.

Comment: It showed the table which made me confused but I have my answer. Thanks.